Internal Server Error, The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request
hi everyone i am getting error 500 i don't know how to get rid of these error so i will be happy if you help me to get out of this error and thanks to you in advance
here is my index.jsp file and on leftside my mavenproject is visible
this is my web.xml file
and i have created A class called Alien
and i have created AlienResource class and code as follows by image
and this is myResource class 
here is my pom.xml file (3)
and if i run the code using based on alienresource class it is coming like this please help me.
i tried to solve it but i ended up not getting output soo please help me

Welcome to SO. Please do not post code and errors as images, copy it into your question and format with markdown. It would be helpful to familiarise yourself with how to ask a good question and how to provide a minimal reproducible example to try to reproduce the error and debug it.
